# Is it possible to lose my upgraded car?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm afraid to sink money into a car only to have it wiped out by losing it somewhere or hopping into another car. Is it possible to lose my upgraded car by accident or on purpose? How can I recover my car if it disappears?

Comment: It depends how you lose it.  If you purchase it the car will be either be towed or be in your garage.  If you steal it then upgrade it, what happens, entirely spends on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

On GTA Online, you should get a tracker and insurance on your car. Then if it were to be destroyed, you could pay the insurance to replace the car. If another player destroys it, they automatically pay the insurance and you can get the car back for free. All you have to do is call Mors Mutual. And if you lost it, you could get your mechanic to deliver it to you or you can look for it on the map.

On GTA V Story mode, if you destroy it you cant get it back and it gets scrapped, if you lose it or get too far from it, then your car goes to the impound the picture on the map is of a white car the impound is there

Also for both, if you get caught by the police while running in the car, it will be impounded. (On GTA V you have to buy it back, and on GTA Online, you can either steal it back or stand at the gate and pay to get it back. And a little tip, if you get the car delivered to you or store it in the garage (then leave and reenter the garage), then it will be automatically repaired for free.

Comment: Almost correct. In story mode the car will also get impounded if you lose it(or get too far away from it). You maybe have to wait a little bit or go to sleep until the car is in the impound garage. Only 2 cars can be impounded. If a third car is parked in this garage, the first one gets removed and can never be retreived again.

Comment: In GTA online, does insurance also replace mods you've put on the car?

Answer (score 0):

Story mode:

If you pimp out the 3 standard cars of the main characters (+ the motorcycle) they will stay like that, any other car that you modify and blow up/lose is lost most likely or ends up in the car impound.